Mid_point label placement using Geometry Generator in QGIS
I've tried to place a label at the start, end, and middle of my lines in QGIS using the Geometry Generator.
This post, place-label-along-line-near-start-and-end-of-line-in-qgis, got me the start and end but I'd also like to put label/s along the middle, especially on long lines.
collect_geometries(
    line_substring($geometry, 0, 1),
    reverse(
        line_substring(reverse($geometry), 0, 1)
        )
    )

I've tried centroid($geometry) and line_interpolate_point($geometry, $length/2) and I was even thinking something like (start plus end /2). I've also modified the font size in case there were some overlap removals.
I'm likely not understanding how line_substring() in the Geometry Generator works.

When 0 means the start point and 1 means the end point, then the value in the middle is simply 0.5.

I tried that, replacing 0 or 1 at each point in the above expression with 0.5, and it didn't add a point, in the middle or otherwise.

Find the midpoint by line_interpolate_point with distance=line length/2:
collect_geometries(
    start_point($geometry),  
    line_interpolate_point($geometry, $length/2),
    end_point($geometry)
    )



Thanks for answer. I played around as it didn't work straight away. I did get it to work but only with $length/0.002?

Maybe the algorithm gets confused because the distance units are millimeters?

Maybe, try map units
